# Value of the input field should not be editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form in my Hotel Management System. It's the registration of Room form. So the Room Number depends on the Floor (+ 2 to 4 digits). Here's how it looks:

[image]

So the value that the Floor pass on the Room should not be editable. This is the javascrpit that I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(
        function() { 
            $("#_roomNumber_id").on("keydown", function(e) {
                   if (($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 0 && (e.keyCode < 35 || e.keyCode > 40))
                       || ($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 1 && e.keyCode == 8)) {
                       return false;
                }
               });

               $("#_roomNumber_id").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
               }); 
            }); 
//]]>
</script>
```

But the only thing that the javascript do is disable the characters base on the number that you declare on this line `($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 1 && e.keyCode == 8)` and it shouldn't be like that, the whole value of the floor pass should not be editable. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled> Try the attribute disabled

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar the whole input field will be disabled Sir.

Comment: So only the numbers i.e 01 should be editable is it?

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar Yes Sir.

Comment: Check my answer hope it will give you some idea

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar I'll try it Sir then update you. :)

Comment: FIne Sir! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129405/discussion-between-karthik-sivakumar-and-kendall-h).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/Yt72H/571/) helps you to get the solution

```
<input id="field" type="text" value="Basement-" size="10" />

<div id="output">
</div>

var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;

$('#output').text(readOnlyLength);

$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
 var $field = $(this);
 $('#output').text(event.which + '-' + this.selectionStart);
 if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
    && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
    || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm having some problem Sir. Cause the value that shouldn't be edited is the value from the floor(id = "_floor_id") that will be pass in the room number field(id = "_roomNumber_id") so I tried this: http://pastie.org/private/ichfnsradby3diwsnkudjw but It's not working.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and share with me?

Comment: Just updated it Sir: http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/573/ The only problem there is it's just getting the lenght of the first selected option but when I tried to change the selected it doesn't get the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript to disable the select input control by using the `onchange` event handler! 
here goes a sample plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/r1jR75NvI2QfzIiMeHsu?p=preview

Comment: @kendall if it didnt work then provide your plunkr so we can check the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the "Input Group" feature of bootstrap (if you're using bootstrap, that is). See this link: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/